# Espresso : how to access text from web view

Tags: android, android-espresso

Friends please help me  to get text within a webview using XPATH.
I am trying to access value 3,427 however the below code fails.
I am trying to store it in a variable for further calculations

String s =onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//*[@id='promo-goal']/div[2]/div[2]/dl/dd[1]")).toString();

```
<dl>
  <dt class="earned">
    ::before
    COLLECTED
  </dt>

  <dd>
   3,427
    <span> pts.</span>
  </dd>
  </dl>
```